# How to allow only numbers and bar, point and hyphen?

Tags: regex, if-statement

So because I need to not allow mostly all special characters, I tried to use ! on my if with this regex [z0-9.-/], but if I write special characters and numbers they match, and don't have to match.

```
regex = [z0-9.-\/];    
if(!this.variable.match(this.regex) {
    return something;
    }
    else if...
```

If i write @@122

I not received 'something'.

Comment: If you are using JavaScript, you have to write the pattern with the delimiters. Also, you get a partial match as the pattern is unanchored. With anchors it would be `const regex = /^[z0-9.-\/]+$/;` to match the whole string.

Comment: @AlexiaRibeiro please review your question, it is not clear the ask. Please provide several examples of the input you want to parse and the expected result on each case. You can use the following page to write your example and check the result: https://regex101.com/